# Cannot setup network interfaces when installing Linux Alpine with setup-alpine

Tags: linux, installation, alpine-linux

I am trying to install Linux Alpine from a USB but it fails on setup-alpine, more specifically on setup-interfaces script. I have the ethernet cable connected and wifi enabled. It doesn't seem to recognize any network interface and I couldn't find any help elsewhere. If I select the defaults it just goes in the following infinite loop:

```
Available interface are: eth0 wlan0
...
Which one do you want to initialize? [eth0]
Ip address for eth0? [dhcp]
Available interface are: wlan0
...
Which one do you want to initialize? [wlan0]
Available wireless networks (scanning):
ip ioctl 0x8914 failed: No error information
wlan     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down


No available wireless networks

Available interface are: eth0 wlan0
[infinite loop from here]
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up WiFi by following https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Connecting_to_a_wireless_access_point?

Answer (score 1):

That user-unfriendly error is coming from `busybox ip` when it tries to set your `wlan0` interface up, and it means that the device is either soft or hard blocked, or both.

Inspect the output of `busybox rfkill list wlan`. If it says soft blocked, then `rfkill unblock wlan` to remove the soft block. If it says hard blocked, then your computer should have a hardware switch somewhere that you can toggle.